# Fix code duplication when updating values in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following function in my python code:

```
def mk_standard_vectors(self, know):

    vector_type = 'k' if know else 'h'
    for name,se in self.sparse_entities.items():
      if name[-1] == vector_type:
        word = se.word
        for feature in (feature for c in se.contexts for feature in c.dlfs):
          self.vector_space.vectors[word][self.vector_space.contexts_to_id[feature]]+=1
          self.vector_space.vectors[feature][self.vector_space.contexts_to_id[word]]+=1
```

Codeclimate complains about code duplication in this function. Specifically, about the two lines reading:

```
self.vector_space.vectors[word][self.vector_space.contexts_to_id[feature]]+=1
self.vector_space.vectors[feature][self.vector_space.contexts_to_id[word]]+=1
```

Those two lines update specific values in numpy arrays. Basically, I have a class *vector_space* with a *vectors* dictionary, which indexes numpy arrays by word values. When I run the above function, for any pair (word, feature), I update the position corresponding to *feature* in the array indexed by *word*, and then the opposite.  Is there any clever way to condense the code and satisfy codeclimate?

(I could write an additional function, of course, but I can't see it would make things particularly cleaner or more efficient. Unless I am missing something...)

Comment: Looks okay to me. What exactly does "codeclimate" complains about? Is there a specific message?

Comment: Thanks for checking. The codeclimate message is rather short. It just says "Similar code found in 1 other location (mass = 33)". And that's two errors, because there are two similar lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would just keep it as-is. It's perfectly clear what you're doing there. Sometimes such guidelines should be ignored - not always but if there are valid reasons to break them you should be allowed to break them.

But if you really want to avoid the warning you could wrap it as "sub-iteration":

```
# ...
for feature in (feature for c in se.contexts for feature in c.dlfs):
    for vec, context in ((word, feature), (feature, word)):
        self.vector_space.vectors[vec][self.vector_space.contexts_to_id[context]] += 1
```